# F# combining two sequences

Tags: f#, functional-programming, sequences

I have two sequences that I would like to combine somehow as I need the result of the second one printed right next to the first. The code is currently where playerItems refers to a list:

```
seq state.player.playerItems
      |> Seq.map (fun i -> i.name)
      |> Seq.iter (printfn "You have a %s")

seq state.player.playerItems
      |> Seq.map (fun i -> i.description) |> Seq.iter (printfn "Description =  %s")
```

The result currently is

```
You have a Keycard
You have a Hammer
You have a Wrench
You have a Screw
Description =  Swipe to enter
Description =  Thump
Description =  Grab, Twist, Let go, Repeat
Description =  Twisty poke
```

However, I need it to be

```
You have a Keycard
Description =  Swipe to enter
You have a Hammer
Description =  Thump
```

Any help with this would be very appreciated.

Comment: `state.player.playerItems
 |> Seq.iter (fun player -> printfn "You have a %s\nDescription =  %s"  player.name player.description)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As Foggy Finder said in the comments, in your specific case you really don't have two sequences, you have one sequence and you want to print two lines for each item, which can be done with a single `Seq.iter` like this:

```
state.player.playerItems  // The "seq" beforehand is not necessary
|> Seq.iter (fun player -> printfn "You have a %s\nDescription = %s" player.name player.description)
```

However, I'll also tell you about two ways to combine two sequences, for the time when you really *do* have two different sequences. First, if you want to turn the two sequences into a sequence of tuples, you'd use `Seq.zip`:

```
let colors = Seq.ofList ["red"; "green"; "blue"]
let numbers = Seq.ofList [25; 73; 42]
let pairs = Seq.zip colors numbers
printfn "%A" pairs
// Prints: seq [("red", 25); ("green", 73); ("blue", 42)]
```

If you want to combine the two sequences in some *other* way than producing tuples, use `Seq.map2` and pass it a two-parameter function:

```
let colors = Seq.ofList ["red"; "green"; "blue"]
let numbers = Seq.ofList [25; 73; 42]
let combined = Seq.map2 (fun clr num -> sprintf "%s: %d" clr num) colors numbers
printfn "%A" combined
// Prints: seq ["red: 25"; "green: 73"; "blue: 42"]
```

Finally, if all you want is to perform some side-effect for each pair of items in the two sequences, then `Seq.iter2` is your friend:

```
let colors = Seq.ofList ["red"; "green"; "blue"]
let numbers = Seq.ofList [25; 73; 42]
Seq.iter2 (fun clr num -> printfn "%s: %d" clr num)
```

That would print the following three lines to the console:

```
red: 25
green: 73
blue: 42
```

Note how in the `Seq.iter` function, I'm not storing the result. That's because the result of `Seq.iter` is always `()`, the "unit" value that is F#'s equivalent of `void`. (Except that it's much more useful than `void`, for reasons that are beyond the scope of this answer. Search Stack Overflow for "[F#] unit" and you should find some interesting questions and answers, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1900962/2314532).