# When to use folly Unit type

Tags: c++, folly

In the following code snippet, I saw this `Unit` type but couldn't figure out when to use it and what it is doing? I read this https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Unit.h but still don't know how to use this Unit in my program. What are the typical scenarios Unit will help?

```
   Future<Unit> fut3 = std::move(fut2)
      .thenValue([](string str) {
        cout << str << endl;
      })
      .thenTry([](folly::Try<string> strTry) {
        cout << strTry.value() << endl;
      })
      .thenError(folly::tag_t<std::exception>{}, [](std::exception const& e) {
        cerr << e.what() << endl;
      });
```

Comment: What weren't you able to figure out from reading the documentation of the class?

Comment: I don't know how to use it? Can you give me few examples where it can be used?

Comment: *Unit* works like *void*.  Also this is feeling like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900962/void-in-constrast-with-unit except for the C++ difference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Void in constrast with Unit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1900962/void-in-constrast-with-unit)

Comment: The standard has [`std::monostate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/monostate) which is the modern C++ unit type as of C++17.  Prior to C++17 (and still extant) many people that find a need for some sort of unit type make their own.

Answer (score 2):

This comes directly from the [comments on the class itself](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/Unit.h) and explains pretty much everything including a use case.

```
/// In functional programming, the degenerate case is often called "unit". In
/// C++, "void" is often the best analogue. However, because of the syntactic
/// special-casing required for void, it is frequently a liability for template
/// metaprogramming. So, instead of writing specializations to handle cases like
/// SomeContainer<void>, a library author may instead rule that out and simply
/// have library users use SomeContainer<Unit>. Contained values may be ignored.
/// Much easier.
///
/// "void" is the type that admits of no values at all. It is not possible to
/// construct a value of this type.
/// "unit" is the type that admits of precisely one unique value. It is
/// possible to construct a value of this type, but it is always the same value
/// every time, so it is uninteresting.
```

Comment: Down-voted because this post does not answer the OP question, "When to use folly Unit type", it just quotes some documentation that doesn't explain when to use the class, and doesn't even explain the class in a way that the OP would understand.

Answer (score 0):

The folly::Unit class provides a **standard** dummy class that is a real type (unlike void), but that by itself is useless, that you can use as a parameter when instantiating a pre-existing template (like folly::Future) and your instantiation of that template does not require or does not use an object corresponding to one or more of the template's typename parameters. A standard dummy type such as folly:Unit is especially useful when a function template parameter is used as the function's return type but the instantiation of the function would otherwise have a void return value.